# Swift: NSCoding Implementation For An Object Without Instance Variables

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

Case in point: Beginner here please bear with me. I just learnt how to persist objects by encoding/decoding & archiving/unarchiving. Problem is now I want to persist a single UIImage. What is the recommended way to do that?

My current implementation that works but looks really weird:

```
class Photo: NSObject, NSCoding {

    static let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("photo")

    static func saveToDisk(selectedPhoto: UIImage) {
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(selectedPhoto, toFile: archiveURL.path)
    }

    static func loadFromDisk() -> UIImage? {
        guard let unarchivedPhoto = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: archiveURL.path) as? UIImage
            else {return nil}
        return unarchivedPhoto
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    }

    convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? Many thanks.

Comment: How would you expect to cast a plist file to an UIImage? If you really want to save an UIImage into a plist file (you shouldn't), you will need first to convert the UIImage to JPEG or PNG data representation.

Comment: ARRH I see now. So I should use UIImageJPEGRepresentation() to convert it then write to a path, is that correct? Sorry I know this is such a noob question.

Comment: yes you need to save it as JPEG or PNG. I recommend using JPEG because PNG would discard the image orientation

Comment: Thank you so much Leo, now I get it! Cheers! God I was so dumb.

Comment: Why does `Photo` conform to `NSCoding`? `Photo` only has static methods. It has no state to persist. Please note that the archiving you are doing in those static methods in no way requires that `Photo` conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just started reading up on persistence and I though it's always either with NSCoding or CoreData. Turns out it's simply writing to documentDirectory. I was just stupid and overthinking stuff. Many thanks!

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Instead of editing your question with the solution, post your solution below as an actual answer.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy, answers added. Also thanks for explaining the persistence concept, before that I thought it simply means saving data in general. You explained it better than the book with 1/100 of the words!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Please add correct file url in place of "filename"

```
func convertImageToDataAndWrite()
{
    let img:UIImage = UIImage(named: "img1.png")!
    let data:NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.7)
    if data != nil
    {
        var check:Bool =  NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data!, toFile: "filename")

    }

}

func readImagefromFile()
{
    let data:NSData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("filename") as! NSData!
    var img:UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I read a bit more of Apple's documentation about Archive and Serialization and here is the missing bit my book did not cover:

Archives provide a means to convert objects and values into an architecture-independent stream of bytes that preserves the identity of and the relationships between the objects and values.

So I believe in this case, the UIImage should not be archived, as there is no relationships to be preserved?

Comment: uiimage is an object which cannot be saved externally like in plist etc, for saving image in plist  you need to convert it in a form of bytes.

Comment: Thanks Gypsa I get the data part now. Besides that, is there any particular advantage of archiving the data vs simply writing without archiving?

Answer (score 0):

I completely misunderstood the use of NSCoding and Archive. "Archives provide a means to convert objects and values into an architecture-independent stream of bytes that preserves the identity of and the relationships between the objects and values."

So to save/load a UIImage simply:

```
// Define path
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,in: .userDomainMask).first!
let photoURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("photo.jpg")

// Convert selectedPhoto to Data and write to path
if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedPhoto, 1) {
    try? data.write(to: photoURL)
}

// Load Data and init UIImage
UIImage(contentsOfFile: photoURL.path)
```